# Keep merging cursors together

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-cursor

I am taking the cursor from the row clicked in the bottom list and merging that with the cursor in the top. It works correctly for the first clicked row. But when I click another row, it just replaces the other row not just keeps adding them together. I am not sure if you can or how you can iterate MergeCursor to just keep adding to the cursor not replacing it.

```
public class TopFragment extends Fragment {
    public Cursor mTopCursor;
    EmployeeDBHandler dbHandler;
    ListView mTopListView;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_list, container, false);
        String table = "employees";
        int mStartingEmployeeID = mStartingNumber;
        dbHandler = new EmployeeDBHandler(getContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        mTopCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + "Employee_number" + "=" + mStartingEmployeeID, null);
        mTopListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mTopList);
        TopListCursorAdapter topAdapter = new TopListCursorAdapter(getContext(), mTopCursor);
        mTopListView.setAdapter(topAdapter);
        return view;
    }


    public void update(Cursor cursor) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            MergeCursor mergeCursor = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[]{cursor, mTopCursor});
            TopListCursorAdapter topAdapter = new TopListCursorAdapter(getContext(), mergeCursor);
            mTopListView.setAdapter(topAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

I understand I am always adding the mTopCursor to the merge so it is just taking the mTopCursor and merging with the new cursor that is being passed into update method. I am lost on how I merge the two cursors together, then take the new cursor and merge it with any cursor being passed into update method.

```
public class TopListCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public interface TopListClickListener {
        void onTopListClick(Cursor cursor);
    }

    private TopListClickListener mCallback;

    public TopListCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
        if(!(context instanceof TopListClickListener)) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Content must implement BottomListClickListener");
        }
        this.mCallback = (TopListClickListener) context;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contact_cardview_top, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvFirstName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personFirstName);
        holder.tvLastName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personLastName);
        holder.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personTitle);
        holder.mPeepPic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
        holder.mDetailsButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fullDetailButton);
        holder.mTopCardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.mTopHomeScreenCV);

        String mFirstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("First_name"));
        String mLastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Last_name"));
        String mPayrollTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Payroll_title"));
        String mThumbnail = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ThumbnailData"));

        holder.tvFirstName.setText(mFirstName);
        holder.tvLastName.setText(mLastName);
        holder.tvTitle.setText(mPayrollTitle);

        if (mThumbnail != null) {
            byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(mThumbnail.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap parsedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
            holder.mPeepPic.setImageBitmap(parsedImage);
        } else {
            holder.mPeepPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_place_holder_adapter);
        }


        final int position = cursor.getPosition();
        holder.mDetailsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                String mEmployeeNumber = cursor.getString(1);
                String mEmail = cursor.getString(8);
                String mFirstName = cursor.getString(2);
                String mLastName = cursor.getString(3);
                String mPhoneMobile = cursor.getString(4);
                String mPhoneOffice = cursor.getString(5);
                String mCostCenter = cursor.getString(10);
                String mHasDirectReports = cursor.getString(7);
                String mTitle = cursor.getString(6);
                String mPic = cursor.getString(9);
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, EmployeeFullInfo.class);
                mIntent.putExtra("Employee_number", mEmployeeNumber);
                mIntent.putExtra("Email", mEmail);
                mIntent.putExtra("First_name", mFirstName);
                mIntent.putExtra("Last_name", mLastName);
                mIntent.putExtra("Phone_mobile", mPhoneMobile);
                mIntent.putExtra("Phone_office", mPhoneOffice);
                mIntent.putExtra("Cost_center_id", mCostCenter);
                mIntent.putExtra("Has_direct_reports", mHasDirectReports);
                mIntent.putExtra("Payroll_title", mTitle);
                mIntent.putExtra("ThumbnailData", mPic);
                mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                v.getContext().startActivity(mIntent);
            }
        });

        holder.mTopCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mCallback != null) {
                    mCallback.onTopListClick(cursor);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvFirstName;
        TextView tvLastName;
        TextView tvTitle;
        ImageView mPeepPic;
        ImageButton mDetailsButton;
        CardView mTopCardView;
    }
}


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomListCursorAdapter.BottomListClickListener,
        TopListCursorAdapter.TopListClickListener {
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    EmployeeDBHandler dbHandler;
    private TopListCursorAdapter topAdapter;
    private BottomListCursorAdapter bottomAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Employee> mEmployee;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        dbHandler = new EmployeeDBHandler(getApplicationContext());
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        getXMLData();

        //GUI for seeing android SQLite Database in Chrome Dev Tools
        Stetho.InitializerBuilder inBuilder = Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this);
        inBuilder.enableWebKitInspector(Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(this));
        Stetho.Initializer in = inBuilder.build();
        Stetho.initialize(in);
    }

    public void getXMLData() {
        OkHttpClient client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(getString(R.string.API_FULL_URL))
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                final String responseData = response.body().string();
                final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseData.getBytes());
                final XMLPullParserHandler parserHandler = new XMLPullParserHandler();
                final ArrayList<Employee> employees = (ArrayList<Employee>) parserHandler.parse(stream);

                for (Employee e : employees) {
                    dbHandler.addEmployee(e);
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        displayTopList();
                        displayBottomList();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public void displayTopList() {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.topFragment, new TopFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    public void displayBottomList() {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.bottomFragment, new BottomFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBottomListClick(Employee e) {
        dbHandler.addEmployee(e);
        Log.i("EMPLOYEE", e.toString());
        TopFragment topFragment = (TopFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.topFragment);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        final Cursor clickedEmployee = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + "employees" + " WHERE " +
                "Employee_number" + "=" + e.getEmployee_number(), null);
        // change the adapter's Cursor
        topFragment.update(clickedEmployee);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTopListClick(Cursor cursor) {
        do{
            BottomFragment bottomFragment = (BottomFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.bottomFragment);
            bottomFragment.refreshList(cursor);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems there could be better solution for your problem, can you please let me know what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have a ListView that when clicked sends that rows cursor to the top ListView to show that row in the ListView there. As the user clicks the bottom ListView the top ListView should keep adding those row clicks.

Comment: @Deepesh not sure if there is another way for me to do this as this is pretty much the functionality the app needs. I only know how to pass the cursor from one listview to another, so I would assume I would just have to keep adding the cursors together in the top fragment to keep building up that listview. I know what my problem is, just not sure how to correct it. It's the mTopCursor. I am always using that, and not the latest merged cursor the next time a bottom list row is clicked.

Comment: added my answer below please have a look..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a very basic project just to achieve your requirement, please find the link of repo below:

https://github.com/deeps09/AdamGardner

```
public class TopFragment extends Fragment {
    public Cursor mTopCursor;
    EmployeeDBHandler dbHandler;
    ListView mTopListView;
    public static MatrixCursor customCursor1;
    private int mStartingEmployeeID = mStartingNumber;
    int flag = 0;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_list, container, false);
        String table = "employees";

        customCursor1 = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{"_id", "Employee_number", "First_name",
                "Last_name", "Payroll_title", "ThumbnailData"});
        dbHandler = new EmployeeDBHandler(getContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        mTopCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + "Employee_number" + "=" + mStartingEmployeeID, null);
        mTopListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mTopList);
        TopListCursorAdapter topAdapter = new TopListCursorAdapter(getContext(), mTopCursor);
        mTopListView.setAdapter(topAdapter);
        return view;
    }

    public void update(Cursor cursor) {
        if (cursor.moveToNext() && cursor.getCount() >= 1) {
            do {
                customCursor1.addRow(new Object[]{cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),
                        cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(9)});
                if (flag == 0) {
                    customCursor1.addRow(new Object[]{mTopCursor.getInt(0), mTopCursor.getString(1), mTopCursor.getString(2),
                            mTopCursor.getString(3), mTopCursor.getString(6), mTopCursor.getString(9)});
                    flag++;
                }
                TopListCursorAdapter topAdapter = new TopListCursorAdapter(getContext(), customCursor1);
                mTopListView.setAdapter(topAdapter);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: customCursor2.addRow(new Object[]{i, "Item Desc " + l}); Is this what is adding the listView2 click to the listView1? For the most part, I see what is happening just not 100% clear on how to do that in my app. I'm not able to rewrite this application as that would include redoing network calls, database, xml parsing. Just don't have the time for that.

Comment: Or is that onClickListener event possible to do in a custom CursorAdapter? I have a CursorAdapter for the bottomList that is passing the cursor to the MainActivity that is then passing it to the TopFragment where I am doing the MergeCursor.

Comment: I understand that, but I cannot use a SimpleCursorAdapter for how I need to display each row with the data coming back from a web service. So I am not sure how to implement this into my own code where I get the same results.

Comment: I made SimpleCursorAdapter just to show you the example, it could be any other adapter. What you can do is, update your top listview adapter on BottomListView item click with the underlying data.

Comment: Can you set a listView adapter inside another adapter?

Comment: I am not sure about using one adapter inside another, however, added algorithm in EDIT 3, please try to implement it in your app..

Comment: is .add(object) a custom method? My CursorAdapter does not have the .add method if its not a custom one.

Comment: WIll it be possible for you to share your code, I mistakenly assumed that you are using ArrayAdapter hence suggested you to call .add() method, my bad...

Comment: added my TopListCursorAdapter and MainActivity. Not sure if there is anything specific you are looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136178/discussion-between-deepesh-and-adam-gardner).

Comment: Wont let me assign the bounty for 7 more hours.